# How to import react Antd table in HTML?

Tags: html, reactjs, antd

i have been working on a project in which i need to import react component in html format. But i'm stuck how should i import antd components in html.I'm attaching the code here.what is right way of doing this thing
I'm new to coding and this is the first project. much appreciate if anyone could help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>React App</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/3.23.6/antd.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script type='text/jsx'>

  var Box = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
      const data1 = [
        [
          key='0',
          www = 'All India',
          circle= 'All India',
          subHeader1= 12,
          subHeader2= 66,
          subHeader3= 32,
          subHeader4=52,
          subHeader5= 74,
          subHeader6= 32
        ],
        [
          key='0',
          www = '1',
          circle= 'GUJ',
          subHeader1= 42,
          subHeader2= 16,
          subHeader3= 70,
          subHeader4=12,
          subHeader5= 54,
          subHeader6= 33
        ]]
      let data = [
        columns =  [
          [
            active= true,
            columnName = "Class",
            dataIndex= "www",
            id= "1",
            subHeader= null,
            style= {},
            visibility= true
          ],
          [
            active= true,
            columnName = "Circle",
            dataIndex= "circle",
            id= "1",
            subHeader= null,
            style= {},
            visibility= true
          ],
          [
            active= true,
            columnName= "Vodafone",
            id= "1",
            subHeader= [
              [
                month = "March",
                dataIndex= "subHeader1",
                style= []

              ],
              [
                month = "April",
                dataIndex = "subHeader2"

              ],
              [
                month = "May",
                dataIndex ="subHeader3"

              ]
            ]
          ]]
        ]
      const items = data.columns.map(item =>
        (
          item.subHeader ? (<ColumnGroup title={item.columnName}>
            {
              item.subHeader.map((it) => (
                it.style ? (<Column title={it.month} dataIndex={it.dataIndex} key="2"
                                    render={(text) => {
                                      return{
                                        props:{
                                          style: {background: parseInt(text) > 50 ? "#08AE4E" : "#f54840",
                                            color: "white", fontWeight:"bold"}
                                        },
                                        children: <div>{text}</div>
                                      }
                                    }
                                    }
                />): (<Column title={it.name} dataIndex={it.dataIndex} key="2"/>)
              ))
            }
          </ColumnGroup>) : <Column title={item.columnName} dataIndex={item.dataIndex} key="age" />
        )
      )
      return (
        <div>
          <h1></h1>
          <Table dataSource={data1} bordered title='table' >
            {items}
          </Table>
          <h1>NPS</h1>
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

  ReactDOM.render(<Box />, document.getElementById('app'));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In html can't read import component antd directly, you have to use DOM for manipulation or it would be better to separate js and html files